# Recognize touch screen touch as mousedown

Tags: c#, windows, forms, winforms, touchscreen

I'm building an application for use in my research lab that requires subjects to touch and hold a button in windows forms (c#). Windows recognizes touch and hold events as a right click or something and it won't fire the mousedown event.. I need a workaround that allows the form to fire a "mousedown" event on touch. I've tried disabling push-and-hold to rightclick in the OS. 
I'm using windows 10 devices.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered just putting in a context menu handler (that's what will eventually result) and having it call the mousedown event handler. Or, you could handle the right-click event.  One of those should be firing.